# Google Map in Window Store App in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, xaml

Is it possible to use google map API in windows metro style app using C# and XAML ?

Comment: _Did you tried anything?_ Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible. Use JSON or REST Services entailed in the Google MAP API. With those you can do just about any platform. Please state what you've tried, and be more specific in the future.