# Google Map in Windows Store Application

Tags: google-maps-api-3, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to use Google Map in my Windows Store Application. I found this article. http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8. But it is in javascript, I am not a javascript expert. I want to implement it in C# + XAML. How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: The article is in `C#`. Exactly what you are working on.

Comment: @Shivan, article is in JavaScript (WinJS) not in C#

@Bilal, read the comments, `With C#/XAML instead of iframe use a WebView and then NavigateToString after reading the HTML content file as a stream. Once the WebView is populated with your googlely goodness you can communicate with it via InvokeScript. So make the reading on the c# side and pass the readings to the JS side.`

Comment: It is in js,css,html.

Comment: @Xyroid.. Can you make a working example of it. I am confused about it.

Comment: possbile duplicate of Google Map in Window Store App in C#
 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526995/google-map-in-window-store-app-in-c-sharp

Comment: Its not helpful for me.